# ColorData input arguments not clear

Tags: graphics, color

A question about ColorData input arguments.

I want to color a point in a graph I have, but I don't want to use the built in colors (orange, green, blue etc)
I saw someone coloring a point using ColorData function, like so:

```
    Graphics[{ColorData[96, 10], PointSize[Large], Point[{-\[Pi], 0}], 
  Point[{0, 0}], Point[{\[Pi], 0}], Point[{2 \[Pi], 0}], 
  Point[{3 \[Pi], 0}], Point[{4 \[Pi], 0}], Point[{5 \[Pi], 0}]}],
```

(in this case ColorData[96,10] comes out as orange.)
I know that the first argument in colordata should be the color scheme, but what is 96 ? is there a chart of all colors in all schemes and numbered?

Thanks!

Comment: The first value goes from 1-113 and you select a sceme and the second from 1-10

Comment: I am confused, does the accepted answer address your questions? Because I don't see how.

Comment: @Kuba I finished the numbered chart. do you like it?

Comment: @J42161217 I was rather expecting to get an answer to witch, named or whatever scheme, does e.g. ColorData[96] corresponds to. But if that was not OP's question then fine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the numbered chart

```
GraphicsGrid[
Join[{Table[
Graphics[Text[Style[i, Small]], ImageSize -> 20], {i, 0, 10}]}, 
Table[Join[{Graphics[Text[Style[k, Small]], ImageSize -> 20]}, 
Table[Graphics[{ColorData[k, j], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20], {j, 
  10}]], {k, 113}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! this solves my conundrum!

Comment: I'm glad I helped ;)