# How to specify a particular plot marker's colour from Mathematica's automatic list of markers?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a plot like this:

```
data={{{1, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}, {{4, 4}}, {{5, 5}}, {{6, 6}}};
ListPlot[data,  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 25}]
```

[image: Example Plot]

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037832/how-to-specify-a-particular-plot-marker-from-mathematicas-automatic-list-of-mar) I know how to use a specific plot marker from the list of automatic plot markers. But which colour is Mathematica using? Using `ColorData[1][n]` I couldn't find the right Palette yet.

Comment: `ColorData[97]`?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185674/46583

Comment: Yes, 97 is correct, thanks. And that link is great @J42161217

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default color scheme for `ListPlot` is `ColorData[97]`:

```
"DefaultColor" /. Themes`DefaultStyles[ListPlot][[All, 2]]
```

> 97

```
ColorData[97, "Image"]
```

[image]

```
Row[("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /.
  Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, ListPlot]))[[All, 1]]]
```

[image]

```
Row[ListPlot[data,  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 25}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotStyle -> #,   PlotLabel -> Style["PlotStyle -> " <> ToString[#], 16]] & /@ 
 {Automatic, 97}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a list of those defaults or a way to finde the default value? Or do I just have to know, for example, that the default for `ListPlot` is `ColorData[97]`?

Comment: @phoenix-bs, thank you for the accept.  You can use _undocumented_  internal functions ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme`` and ``Themes`DefaultStyles`` to discover the default values for various plot and theme combinations.